# Check if a pod is running on a k8s cluster in a go program

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am writing a command line tool in Go which will perform an action based on the existence of a particular pod on a `k8s` cluster, in a specific namespace.

I could do via command line (shell) invocations within my `go` program something like

```
kubectl get pods -n mynapespace l app=myapp
```

or in case I am not certain about the labels, something even less elegant as:

```
kubectl get pods -n mynapespace | grep -i somepatternIamcertainabout
```

However, given that I am using the k8s native language (Go) I was wondering whether there might be a more Go native/specific way of making such an inquiry to the k8s api server, without resorting to shell invocations from within my cli tool.

Comment: There is no reason to [add tags to your title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). It's just redundant clutter.

Comment: Also annotate/tag your pods with meaningful names. So don't use `grep` - instead search pods/deployments/services by tag.

Answer (score 1):

The kubectl utility is just a convenience wrapper that talks to the Kubernetes API using bog standard HTTP. The Go standard library has a great [http package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/). The perfect fit for what you're trying to accomplish.

In fact, you could just use [this official client package](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) from the Kubernetes project itself.

Comment: Also use [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) to grant your pods read-only `view` type access etc.

Answer (score 1):

> However, given that I am using the k8s native language (Go) I was
>   wondering whether there might be a more Go native/specific way of
>   making such an inquiry to the k8s api server, without resorting to
>   shell invocations from within my cli tool.

If you want to talk with **k8s cluster** in your programs written in **go** without resorting to shell invocations, [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) library is the way to go. It contains everything you need to query your k8s api server in your go programs.

> #### What's included
>
> - The `kubernetes` package contains the clientset to
>     access Kubernetes API.
> - The `discovery` package is used to discover APIs
>     supported by a Kubernetes API server.
> - The `dynamic` package contains a
>     dynamic client that can perform generic operations on arbitrary
>     Kubernetes API objects.
> - The `plugin/pkg/client/auth` packages contain
>     optional authentication plugins for obtaining credentials from
>     external sources.
> - The `transport` package is used to set up auth and
>     start a connection.
> - The `tools/cache` package is useful for writing
>     controllers.